# What do I need to use ffmpeg to convert .mov file to webm?

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal, webm, mov, libvpx

I'm trying to convert .mov files to .webm using ffmpeg from terminal on my Mac. However I don't really get what I should install to complete the conversion: I've installed libvpx

```
brew install libvpx
```

I've installed ffmpeg

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

But still when I'm trying to convert file like this

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mov -c:v libvpx -b:v 2000 vid.webm
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format webm (codec vp8) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually. Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0
```

What should I do then? how do I enable default encoder? is there something I should do differently or something more I need to install?

Comment: Share full log for failing command.

Comment: Here's my own output (running on an M1 Mac installed as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997047/271577 ) where I get the same error: https://gist.github.com/brettz9/a9a33fcba1751f3724ad54606e43653b (though adding `-c:v libvpx` gives me "Unknown encoder 'libvpx'")