# Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)

Tags: macos, arm, homebrew, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon

I use the latest Apple M1 chip processor. And I keep getting errors while application installation.

I run:

```
brew install openjdk@11
```

```
Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
  brew bundle dump
```

Need help with exact steps to follow.

Comment: still same for OpenJDK 17

Answer (score 466, accepted):

For what it's worth, before installing Homebrew you will need to install Rosetta2 emulator for the new ARM silicon (M1 chip). I just installed Rosetta2 via terminal using:

`/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`

This will install rosetta2 with no extra button clicks.

After installing Rosetta2 above you can then use the Homebrew cmd and install Homebrew for ARM M1 chip:  `arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`

Once Homebrew for M1 ARM is installed use this Homebrew command to install packages: `arch -x86_64 brew install <package>`

Comment: I have already installed HomeBrew in this path /opt/homebrew/ and installed Nginx and PHP too which is working properly. Does this break if I execute the above command?

Comment: After this command : `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license` I get `Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported.`

Comment: I am also facing the same issue is there any other workaround for this `Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported.`

Comment: Uncheck run with rosetta in terminal and it can be install Rosetta 2. It works for me

Comment: i unchecked  rosetta in terminal, but it still get that error @DucNguyen

Comment: Quit terminal and then try again.

Comment: I'm wondering what the difference is between this solution and the one @court3nay provided - there 2 instances of brew is installed, one using rosetta, another one for ARM - this one here only uses rosetta, so will I be missing out on anything if I use this option only?

Comment: Add an alias `alias brew86="arch -x86_64 /usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew"` to your `.zshrc` for future convenience

Comment: For those getting the response: "Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink", try: $ sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

Comment: hey, thanks for this btw. After adding your 3rd command to install my package, which in this case is rgdbs - https://rgbds.gbdev.io/install/macos - getting the following error:
`/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37 is not a valid keg` Any ideas?

Comment: I had the error `Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported.`, and solved it by doing the following:
1. I had previously set up my terminal to 'run with Rosetta', so I decided to duplicate it and rename the new application 'Rosetta-Terminal' (optional, but good if you need rosetta for other things)
2. Unchecked 'run with rosetta' in 'get info' of 'Terminal'.
3. Quit and Reopen Terminal... ran the command and it worked

Comment: If you have a Brewfile to install -- I used `arch -x86_64 /usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew  bundle --file ~/Brewfile` to install the packages that require Rosetta correctly.

Comment: Rosetta not enough for you? Try Rosetta2!

Comment: Thanks! I had to use `arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew install <package>` because `arch -x86_64 brew install <package>` failed with "Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!".

Comment: `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license` didn't work for the first time, I had to reopen my terminal. And istalling package also encontered problem. I had to use `arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew install <package>`

Answer (score 150):

Homebrew needs to be installed in two places on Apple silicon: in /usr/local for rosetta-emulated (Intel) code, and /opt/homebrew for ARM64. These are somewhat hard-coded and the /opt/homebrew one MUST be used for ARM code, as it stands today, and is [non-negotiable](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/9130). However, it's easy enough to install and you can follow the general instructions on the [official docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation). You open a Rosetta shell first.

```
% arch -x86_64 zsh
% cd /usr/local && mkdir homebrew
% curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

Later, to install tools under intel you can use the arch command per-command or open a zsh terminal as above.

```
arch -x86_64 /usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew install sometool
```

For the ARM architecture, you don't need to use `arch` but you do need to use the full path of the homebrew command.

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew install sometool
```

You could rename the brew commands to something like brew86 and brewARM to help keep them separate.

Comment: "You could rename the brew commands to something like brew86 and brewARM to help keep them separate" - How exactly to do this?

Comment: @indojin You can use a ZSH alias. By adding `alias brew86="arch -x86_64 /usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew"` and `alias brewARM="/opt/homebrew/bin/brew"` to your `~/.zshrc` file

Comment: I also used the alias. I wonder why this is not standard for the homebrew installation... ;)

Comment: How do you know if want to install something to 86 or ARM?

Comment: Thanks. The approved answer did not work for me for some reason. But after I ran the commands including CURL. I have been able to install the package.

Comment: @TyConway normally you would want to use ARM unless there's some special reason not to. ARM means you're using the native instruction set for the new Apple ARM chips (M1, M2, etc) instead of using the emulated legacy x86 instruction set. The native instruction set is faster than the emulated legacy instruction set.

Comment: Don't forget to run `source ~/.zshrc` after adding new aliases in order to make your terminal recognise them.

Comment: In my case I migrated an Intel-based MBP to an ARM-based MBP. The former had already installed homebrew and that version is the one that ended up accessible from the command line after migrating. I just had to reinstall homebrew in the new MBP executing the official command `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`. This installed homebrew in /opt/homebrew and made it the default brew command. Anyhow, this answer and @NBTX's comment were both helpful.

Answer (score 127):

Run this in the terminal it fixes the issue

`eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

Comment: After running this I was able to run `brew install php` with no problems

Comment: + adding that line to your shell (.zshrc on my case) prevents you from having to write that line every time you close and open the terminal

Comment: This fixed my issue after running a `$ brew doctor`

Comment: This fixed my issue with the following error:

Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
  brew bundle dump

Comment: After running this I was able to run brew install python@3.8

Comment: the error `Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!` will be fixed with this command.

Comment: What is actually this command do?

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you @gandharv garg!!

Answer (score 68):

Just use:

```
arch -arm64 brew install package-name
```

replace 'package-name' with the package you want to install.

Comment: This was the simple answer for my 2021 M1 Max running on Monterey 12.1. If new to nginx, read the output of the install. You do need to start the service and by default it's listening on port 8080 on version 1.21.6_1 of nginx.

Comment: didn't work for me to upgrade node

Comment: it worked for me with M1 mac.

Comment: It worked for me to install poetry

Comment: It didn't worked for me. :( I got this error `Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!`

Comment: Not work for me M2 mac.

Answer (score 60):

There is a lot of helpful info in the replies here, but there doesn't seem to be a direct answer to the original request, "*Need help with exact steps to follow.*"

In case it may help people facing this issue in the future, I'll share the exact steps that I followed to resolve the issue.

The following CLI commands are intended to be run on an Apple silicon-equipped Mac in the built-in Terminal application running the macOS-default shell, Zsh:

1. Run a Homebrew command to confirm that an error like the following appears:

   ```
   $ brew install <formula>
   ```

   ```
   Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
   Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
   "Alternative Installs" from:
     https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   $ brew doctor
   ```

   ```
   Warning: Your Homebrew's prefix is not /opt/homebrew.
   Some of Homebrew's bottles (binary packages) can only be used with the default
   prefix (/opt/homebrew).
   You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
   ```

   If either of these errors appears, it is likely that the steps below are applicable to your case.
2. Navigate to the `/opt` folder:

   ```
   $ cd /opt
   ```
3. Create a folder named `homebrew`. By default superuser privileges are required to write inside of the `/opt` folder, which means that it is necessary to use `sudo`:

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir homebrew
   ```
4. Grant write access to the `homebrew` folder so that your user can perform the Homebrew installation:

   ```
   $ sudo chmod go+w homebrew
   ```
5. Perform the four steps listed on the "[Alternative Installs](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#alternative-installs)" page (the page mentioned in the first error message in step 1):

   1. Install Homebrew:

      ```
      $ curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
      ```
   2. Set Homebrew's prefix in your current Terminal session:

      ```
      $ eval "$(homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
      ```
   3. Update Homebrew:

      ```
      $ brew update --force --quiet
      ```
   4. Revoke write access to specific folders and files:

      ```
      $ chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh"
      ```
6. Set Homebrew's prefix in future Terminal sessions by adding the necessary command to one of Zsh's startup files. As far as I can tell, `.zshrc` is the [preferred startup file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout) for this type of command:

   ```
   $ echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zshrc
   ```

   Note that if there are any other existing Terminal sessions on your machine that have been open since before running the above command, the correct Homebrew prefix will still be unset in those sessions.
7. Confirm that Homebrew's prefix is now properly set:

   ```
   $ type -a brew
   ```

   ```
   brew is /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
   brew is /usr/local/bin/brew
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   $ brew doctor
   ```

   ```
   Your system is ready to brew.
   ```

It should now be possible to continue using Homebrew normally.

Comment: This really helped me, but I ran into some errors while following the listed steps.
When running `brew update --force --quiet`, right after `Initialized empty Git repository in /opt/homebrew/.git/`, the next line was `fatal: not in a git directory`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61001647/4796536) made me think that it's a permission issue, so I created the .git folder manually. After that it looked like it's working, but then it stopped with `Error: update-report should not be called directly!`. Nevertheless, after this, I was still able to use brew properly.

Comment: @KarsaiPéter, if you run `brew doctor` or `brew config`, are any problems reported? One idea is that Xcode Command Line Tools aren't installed. `xcode-select -p` to check if installed; `xcode-select --install` to install. Another idea is [suggested here](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/3315#discussioncomment-2842510): Are you using an admin account? Or maybe it would help if your user were the owner of the `/opt/homebrew` folder? Perhaps try `chown -R $USER /opt/homebrew` (with `sudo` if needed) and then reinstall Homebrew.

Comment: I also got `fatal: not in a git directory /opt/homebrew/.git` error message, even though `brew doctor` shows Your system is ready to brew. Manually adding that .git repo will cause brew doctor to throw : "Warning: Missing https://github.com/Homebrew/brew git origin remote." error message. I then `rm -r /opt/homebrew/.git/` the warning went away from `brew doctor`. I believe this approach is to reuse the old .git repo (for Intel-based CPU installations) instead using the "default" Apple Silicon chip installation. As long as `brew doctor` works, no issues.

Comment: This is the best answer! Well-explained, well formatted, in-depth answer! This answer should get more votes!

Comment: This answer just saved me possibly hours of manual debugging. Thank you!

Comment: If you're getting `fatal: not in a git directory /opt/homebrew/.git`, it is because its expecting ure inside a git repo. 
Try the other method which is `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew homebrew
` as stated here https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#alternative-installs

Answer (score 37):

Did a temporary fix by enabling `Open using Rosetta` option in the terminal app from `Utilities` folder.

However, it would be great to know the actual solution for this question to use the native way.

[image]

Comment: This works and doesn't require brew to be installed twice.

Comment: Wrong @dwaz. this just means all your brew commands by default will be for intel

Comment: tks, this works, i remember to try run a macos project with flutter, make modifcations to wezterm to use neovim, pff

Comment: Before setting `Open using Rosetta`, set the `iTerm`'s `Profile` `Command` to the `x86_64` version of the shell to be used.

Answer (score 22):

This issue with new macbook pro M1 chip

Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!

For Resolve follow below steps

> Step1
>
> **$ brew bundle dump**
>
> Step2
>
> **$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"**
>
> Step3
> Edit file below

> **$ vi ~/.bashrc or vi ~/.zshrc**
>
> Edit below line in above file

> **export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH**

Comment: Problem with this is that in the end you will eventually need to use both homebrew versions. The answer should at least point out the consequences of this change... ;)

Comment: my answer based on M1 chips and my experience

Comment: Seconding @Martin's note above.  Regardless of your experiences, it'd be good to make folks aware.

Comment: M1 - worked perfectly

Answer (score 14):

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

### 1. Clone homebrew

```
$ cd /opt
$ sudo git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew homebrew
```

### 2. Chown dir

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff /opt/homebrew
```

#### 3. Update new brew shellenv temporarily, more shellenv meaning see `man brew`

```
$ eval "$(homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

#### 4. New brew update

```
$ brew update --force --quiet
==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formula and cask analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics have been recorded yet (nor will be during this `brew` run).

==> Tapping homebrew/core
Cloning into '/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1265097, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (207/207), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (97/97), done.
remote: Total 1265097 (delta 120), reused 192 (delta 110), pack-reused 1264890
Receiving objects: 100% (1265097/1265097), 517.64 MiB | 3.02 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (872476/872476), done.
Tapped 3 commands and 6273 formulae (6,616 files, 566.4MB).
```

#### 5. Make sure remove other person write privage

```
$ chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh"
```

#### 6. Confirm new brew version

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 3.6.0
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 57f5c02ec6a; last commit 2022-09-10)
```

#### 7. Brew config show

```
/opt/homebrew on  stable (93ea8cb2c)  17:17:54
$ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.6.0
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 93ea8cb2c40e1ef25f1489b0267526bd47bc8030
Last commit: 3 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 57f5c02ec6af877482ecd8753066d6a277cd3213
Core tap last commit: 72 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /opt/homebrew/Cellar
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 10
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.8 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: 10-core 64-bit westmere
Clang: 13.1.6 build 1316
Git: 2.32.1 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.79.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 12.5.1-x86_64
CLT: 13.4.0.0.1.1651278267
Xcode: 13.4.1
Rosetta 2: true
```

#### 8. Add new brew shellenv to strart bash shell, eg. `~/.zshrc`、`~/.barshrc` etc.

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Comment: This is starting from a place where you do not have brew installed. The OP seems to have brew installed and expects it to work. What do you do if you already have the directory /opt/homebrew? How can you safely transition from the state I described to the end state the OP desires, brew installed and functional on M1 mac?

Answer (score 12):

Probably this error is related running brew on M1/M2 Mac instead instead of Intel based Mac, atleast that was in my case. I had previously restored a Time Machine backup from Intel to M2.

According to the Homebrew documentation, the default installation script installs Homebrew to its preferred `/usr/local`for macOS Intel and /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon.

You can well use this, as it worked well for me-

1. re-install brew by running this in your terminal `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
2. run `brew bundle dump`

You should be good on using `brew`

Answer (score 11):

Homebrew is now available for the new apple M1 chip at https://docs.brew.sh/Installation. The script installs in a new location, ‘/opt/homebrew’ instead of ‘/usr/local’ which requires that you implement a couple lines of script after the install, substituting your username. You can copy/paste from the comments in your install. Just don’t skip these steps.

```
==> Next steps:
- Add Homebrew to your PATH in /Users/[username]/.zprofile:
    echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew [username])"' >> /Users/[username]/.zprofile
    eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew [username])"
```

Note: This works for a clean install of Homebrew on a new machine. If you have already installed an old version of Homebrew and got it working, I believe you need to uninstall that first -or- you may find this a quicker work-around http://blog.wafrat.com/homebrew-on-mac-with-m1/. Not tested.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Note that to uninstall Homebrew, see https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew.

Comment: I installed with the new .pkg installer and running `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew [username]` gives an error. I just made this alias `alias brewlicon="/opt/homebrew/bin/brew"` that I can use whenever I need the silicon version

Comment: and I added `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin`. Adding it to the end is intentional. I default to the normal brew in /usr/local, but use `brewlicon` if I need to

Answer (score 8):

- Background

  - brew location/version

    - default=X86=`Intel`: `/usr/local`
    - `M1/M2`=`arm`=Apple Silicon: `/opt/homebrew`
- Has Done

  - Installed Rosetta
  - x86 brew

    - `arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
- **Solution**

  - for `arm`=`Apple Silicon` package

    - `arch -arm64 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew install package_name`
  - for `x86`=`Intel` package

    - `arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew install package_name`
- Optimization

  - add alias to startup script (eg `~/.zshrc`)

    ```
    alias armbrew="arch -arm64 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew"
    alias x86brew="arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew"
    ```

    - then can use

    ```
    armbrew install package_name
    x86brew install package_name
    ```

Answer (score 4):

First run this command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

then it will ask you a question, hit return, then wait for the installation to be completed. After than run this command:

```
brew bundle dump
```

Comment: This works but it's missing some steps. After you run the first command make sure you run the two commands brew asks you to run.

And after running `brew bundle dump` move the BrewFile created by `brew bundle dump` into `opt/homebrew`. From that directory, run `brew bundle install`. `brew bundle dump` doesn't install the packages, it just creates a BrewFile that tells brew what packages it should install when you run `brew bundle install`. Like a package.json file in node.js.

Comment: An additional note to Dashiell's comment: make sure you run `brew bundle dump` with `/usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew` or otherwise you'll be executing the newly installed `brew`, which won't have access to the old packages.

Answer (score 4):

This also may occur if you are trying to run your command in IntelliJ Terminal. Just try to run in (Regular) Terminal.

Comment: This happened to me trying to install homebrew from the VSCode terminal. Just use a Regular terminal.

Answer (score 3):

For M1 Mac's use following:

```
arch -arm64 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew install SOME_TOOL
```

Example:

```
arch -arm64 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew install gitguardian/tap/ggshield
```

Answer (score 2):

Go over to https://brew.sh and use the command. It will download and install brew again correctly.

Comment: Worked in an M2 mac computer with backup restored from an Intel Mac

Answer (score 0):

I had installed Homebrew using iTerm enabled for the Apple ARM chip (M1), but when using a different terminal program that was Intel-based (and thus opening in Rosetta) I got this error. The latter app is seen as Intel, and thus wants to use the older Homebrew path.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command as this will resolve the issue

```
arch -arm64 brew install kotlin
```

Comment: arch: Unknown architecture: arm64

Answer (score 0):

Brew, Git, etc for intel processors vs. the m1 and m2 chips is in different locations, but with migrating from an old mac, Apple doesn't protect users from these issues, and leaves you to solve on your own.  In fact, they seem to encourage migrating your incompatible tools.

In latest Macs with M2 processor, this process is most easily, and curiously least documented, accomplished this way:

1. Uninstall with the uninteractive command:

   ```
   NONINTERACTIVE=1 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
   ```

   Copy the entire two lines above.  [Here is the link for it.](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew)

   For some reason that un-installs every version of brew, while the default uninstall command doesn't.  To be safe, maybe uninstall with the first command of:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
   ```

   Then uninstall with the noninteractive.  in any event, if you type "brew" in your terminal after the uninstall, you should get an non recognized command, if you don't you have one of the brew's installed.
2. Now that brew is gone, install:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```

   [Found here.](https://brew.sh/)
3. After doing that, brew will give you 2 more commands to install to ensure you can run brew from any directory.  Don't skip that.  The command is custom for your username.

Answer (score 0):

For the lazy among us, just set an alias in your `.zshrc`/`.bashrc` that remaps `brew` with the `arch -arm64` prefix:

```bash
alias brew="arch -arm64 brew"
```

Elegant? No. Works? Yes.

Answer (score -1):

So I bought a new M1 and migrated to it.  I took it back and migrated back.  I was receiving this error.  Found that I needed to run sudo rm -Rf /opt/homebrew after re-installing brew to get things flowing again.  16G Ram on the M1 didn't replace my workflow with Intel using 64G.