# Import pyaudio doesn't work - Symbol not found: _PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap on mac (Big Sur M1 Apple Silicon)

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio, apple-silicon, apple-m1

I am trying to install pyaudio on my new Macbook Air with the M1 chip (Big Sur). At first I couldn't get past the famous `src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found` error. I remember I had this issue on my other laptop as well, but then a simple `brew install portaudio` fixed it. **Well, not this time.**

After trying a lot of different things, finally I found [this guide](http://www.cdotson.com/2019/03/installing-pyaudio-on-macos/) and after finding my homebrew directory, I could do:
`export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/:$LIBRARY_PATH` - same with C_INCLUDE

**After I did this, pyaudio installed fine!** However, now I'm getting an error when I try to import pyaudio to any python program and run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bende/GitHub/fretboard-learner/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pyaudio
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

I tried googling it but to no avail, I'm really not sure what is happening. All I can think of is that it **has to do something with the M1 chip**, because the install worked just fine on a non-M1 mac.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 11):

Don't know if you still need the solution, but here was mine after hours of googling (I also owned a Mac m1):

I could not install PyAudio at first and encountered problems even after I successfully installed PyAudio. I used python 3.9 installed with brew for the process.

0. uninstall previous version of portaudio + PyAudio
1. (optional) Install the latest Brew supported for Mac m1 using the command on the Brew homepage
2. (optional) Install wheel and setuptools: python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
3. Install the latest version of portaudio (I believe this is the core problem, stable version 19.6.0 did not work): brew install portaudio --HEAD
4. Install PyAudio with pip: python3 -m pip install pyaudio --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="-I/opt/homebrew/include" --global-option="-L/opt/homebrew/lib"

Restart terminal might help if things did not go well.

Comment: I saw the steps you took - and I thought ... full marks for effort... lets have a go. This worked well for me  - many thanks. 

Mac -  Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0
Python - 3.9.1

Comment: It still works!!!!

Comment: The pip -global-option was not working for me. The quick fix that worked for me was copying the include and libraries into the conda environments include and library path

Answer (score 1):

#### For Intel-based homebrew installation

For those who must use python packages which are not yet available for the arm-architecture, we must revert to intel-based Python packages. This is not trivial and took me almost a day, so I describe it to some time for people in need.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Run a terminal under Rosetta
   Get Info | Run under Rosetta
2. Install homebrew as intel-based version

In terminal created in (1), run:

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

3. Create alias for intel-based homebrew

In .bash_profile, insert:

```
alias ibrew="arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew"
```

4. Install boost and boost_python libraries:

With brew from step (3), run:

```
ibrew install --build-from-source -vd boost
ibrew install --build-from-source -vd boost-python3
```

5. Install portaudio

With brew from step (3), run:

```
ibrew install portaudio
ibrew link portaudio
```

KEY: This installs portaudio into /usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0, and must be referenced for the pyaudio installation!!!

6. Install pyaudio

We now can install pyaudio with the portaudio version we installed by intel-based homebrew. The version number after /portaudio/ may differ, please adjust to yours.

```
python -m pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib' --force pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

While troubleshooting the same (including following the steps from momoclouq's answer on this question) I ran into this error as well. My final solution was:

My homebrew was only installed in /usr/local which is for rosetta-emulated (Intel) code. See more information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963370/error-cannot-install-in-homebrew-on-arm-processor-in-intel-default-prefix-usr) Stackoverflow question/answer.

Once I had the correct homebrew installation for ARM64 under `/opt/homebrew` I removed my previous portaudio installation and did the following:

- `$arch -arm64 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew install portaudio`
- `$pip3 install --no-cache-dir --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib' pyaudio` *Make sure this path aligns with your arch arm64 portaudio installation.*

Answer (score 0):

The first answer was helpful, but global-option doesn't work anymore, so here's an updated sequence of commands:

(I ran this on a Mac M1)

```
# uninstall previous version of portaudio + PyAudio
pip uninstall pyaudio
brew uninstall portaudio
# make sure default stuff set up
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
# reinstall portaudio and pyaudio
brew install portaudio --HEAD
export CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib"
python3 -m pip install pyaudio
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73930804/4656769