# Pyaudio setup on Mac OS X M1

Tags: pyaudio

I am trying in get pyaudio working on my Mac mini M1

pi@pi-mini ~ % python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, May  3 2021, 19:12:05)
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import pyaudio
> > > Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 116, in 
> > > import _portaudio as pa
> > > ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
> > > /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
> > > /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

any idea what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: first `brew install portaudio` second `pip install pyaudio` use these commands

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same and finally figured it out.

My homebrew was only installed in /usr/local which is for rosetta-emulated (Intel) code, hence the architecture mismatch. See more information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963370/error-cannot-install-in-homebrew-on-arm-processor-in-intel-default-prefix-usr) Stackoverflow question/answer.

Once I had the correct homebrew installation for ARM64 under `/opt/homebrew` I removed my previous portaudio installation did the following:

- `$arch -arm64 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew install portaudio`
- `$pip3 install --no-cache-dir --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib' pyaudio` (More details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709212/import-pyaudio-doesnt-work-symbol-not-found-pamaccore-setupchannelmap-on-ma) Stackoverflow question/answer) *Make sure this path aligns with your arch arm64 portaudio installation.*