# Import pyaudio doesn't work: Symbol not found. Expected in: flat namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I have been trying to install `pyaudio` on a Mac M1 Big Sur but was not able to do so and was stuck on the `'portaudio.h' file not found` error.

I managed to install it using a different pip command: `pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/lib' pyaudio`.

However, after installing when I try to run a script involving `pyaudio`, the script throws the following error:

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "path/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    import pyaudio  
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

Can someone help me with this? I have attempted the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709212/import-pyaudio-doesnt-work-symbol-not-found-pamaccore-setupchannelmap-on-ma) question, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

While troubleshooting the same (including following the steps in the Stackoverflow question you linked) I ran into this error as well. My final solution was:

My homebrew was only installed in /usr/local which is for rosetta-emulated (Intel) code. See more information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963370/error-cannot-install-in-homebrew-on-arm-processor-in-intel-default-prefix-usr) Stackoverflow question/answer.

Once I had the correct homebrew installation for ARM64 under `/opt/homebrew` I removed my previous portaudio installation did the following:

- `$arch -arm64 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew install portaudio`
- `$pip3 install --no-cache-dir --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib' pyaudio` (More details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709212/import-pyaudio-doesnt-work-symbol-not-found-pamaccore-setupchannelmap-on-ma) Stackoverflow question/answer). *Make sure this path aligns with your arch arm64 portaudio installation.*

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me for ARM M1 processor

1. arch -arm64 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew install portaudio
2. pip3 install --no-cache-dir --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib' pyaudio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the answer by Group2.  If you have unique details you want to add, please add them to your answer or suggest an edit of Group2's answer.