# when installing pyaudio, pip cannot find portaudio.h in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0

Tags: python, c, pyaudio, portaudio

Before I start the question, I tried to solve issue with this post, but it did not work: ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include))

I am using mac (M1 air).
I tried to install pyaudio, so I ran `pip install pyaudio`.
Then, I got the following error about not finding portaudio.h:

```html
pip install pyaudio                                                                                                                  
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.12.tar.gz (42 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/sunwoojeong/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/sunwoojeong/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/jm/hwnp4x291qd9n0vw1p4kzw_m0000gn/T/tmpzv_dfxv_
       cwd: /private/var/folders/jm/hwnp4x291qd9n0vw1p4kzw_m0000gn/T/pip-install-y3rg1882/pyaudio_1d880ef087ea42298d89af097d6745ed
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/src
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/sunwoojeong/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sunwoojeong/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DMACOSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Users/sunwoojeong/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:31:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
  #include "portaudio.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

So, After some research I tried to install and link portaudio first like this:

```html
brew install portaudio
brew link portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

Since `brew link portaudio` returns `Warning: Already linked: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0`, I expected that portaudio was installed succesfully and pyaudio should have no issue with portaudio.h file. However, even after installing it, and after explicitly setting the path to the portaudio folder, the pip install command still returns this error.

Here is the pip commands I tried (they all return the same error):

```
pip install pyaudio
pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option="-I$(brew --prefix)/include" --global-option="-L$(brew --prefix)/lib" pyaudio
pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib' pyaudio
```

Has anyone had similar issue and solved it before when installing a python module with some c-lang file?

Answer (score 1):

I think a fix is coming soon. In the meantime, you should be able to workaround the issue by doing this:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib”
pip install pyaudio
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

Try the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64039284/3730626). It suggests you use `--no-binary: all:` like so:

```
sudo pip3 install pyaudio --no-binary :all:
```

Or:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --no-use-pep517 pyaudio
```

The other option is to downgrade `pip`. While I haven't used `pyaudio` before, I have gotten this error with other libraries and one of the above solutions usually fixed it. There is a good possibility that these won't work for you, and there are a lot of different ways this issue can be fixed that are mentioned in SO. One of those solutions will eventually work for you.