# You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoa, cocoapods

I have got a new MacBook, and are trying to install some pods.
I first did `sudo gem install cocoapods` on root, then did `pod install` in the directory I need the pods.
Got this error, and have no clue what went wrong.

From Crash Report:
Process:               ruby [5444]
Path:                  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
Identifier:            ruby
Version:               145.100.1
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [5282]
Responsible:           Terminal [5005]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-09-27 21:24:20.779 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 11.6 (20G165)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:       --D950-78ED-2DF378C6BA5B

Sleep/Wake UUID:      -FE18-47F9-9A4EF2935C96

Time Awake Since Boot: 29000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld3 mode
abort() called.
x
x
x
x
External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=574.8M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=574.8M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=356.4M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=356.4M(100%)

```
                            VIRTUAL   REGION
```

REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced)
===========                     =======  =======
Activity Tracing                   256K        1
Kernel Alloc Once                   32K        1
MALLOC                           105.2M       32
MALLOC guard page                   96K        5
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         240.0M        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.1M        4
Stack                             10.6M        4
VM_ALLOCATE                        1.0G        4
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)              12K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__AUTH                             273K       64
__AUTH_CONST                      3528K      153
__DATA                            1616K      162
__DATA_CONST                      4536K      173
__DATA_DIRTY                       313K       63
__LINKEDIT                       490.7M       27
__OBJC_CONST                       437K       41
__OBJC_RO                         75.1M        1
__OBJC_RW                         2576K        1
__TEXT                            84.2M      185
__UNICODE                          588K        1
shared memory                       32K        2
===========                     =======  =======
TOTAL                              2.1G      927
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.8G      927

Answer (score 97):

Solved by using [homebrew](https://brew.sh)
`brew install cocoapods`

Comment: Make sure you don't have previously installed cocoapods with gem. If so - uninstall it first by typing sudo gem uninstall cocoapods.

Comment: It did the trick for me, but only after removing cocoapods as a gem (?) https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine

Comment: For M1 Chip follow below URLs

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963370/error-cannot-install-in-homebrew-on-arm-processor-in-intel-default-prefix-usr

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652822

Comment: M2 Chip macbook here. Works! Glad I came across this post. Google should have specifically indicated what command to run if Apple chip or not

Answer (score 39):

For those running on Apple Silicon, [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652822) has worked for me:

Uninstall with Ruby: `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

Then, install again with brew: `brew install cocoapods`

Comment: very good. thanks

Comment: Thanks, it helps but in command: brew reinstall cocoapods

Comment: Worked for Macbook pro M2 2022 . Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Try using Rosetta terminal

```
Locate Terminal.app in Finder. (Applications->Terminal.app)
Right-click and choose Get Info
Check the “Open using Rosetta”
Quit all instances of Terminal app and run it again
Run sudo gem install ffi
Run pod install
```

https://armen-mkrtchian.medium.com/run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-and-macos-big-sur-developer-transition-kit-b62acffc1387

Comment: This works for me after trying all other solutions before this. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue, but just had to close **all** instances of my terminal windows after installing cocoapods.

Comment: After few tens of installing with gem, and/or brew, and trying many many things.
Just restart terms has worked like it was magic. incomprehensible
THANK YOU

Answer (score 5):

if you use silicon M1 processor Macbook, you can use below command

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

Then

arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: it did resolve my issue what is ffi

Comment: Ruby-FFI is a gem for programmatically loading dynamically-linked native libraries, binding functions within them, and calling those functions from Ruby code. Moreover, a Ruby-FFI extension works without changes on CRuby (MRI), JRuby, Rubinius and TruffleRuby. @KhurramIqbal

Answer (score 4):

Closing all instances of Terminal, then re-opening terminal and running pod install in the relevant directory did the job for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal.app in Finder. (show in finder)
Right-click and choose Get Info
Check the “Open using Rosetta”
Quit all instances of Terminal app and run it again
type "sudo gem install ffi" and run on terminal
type "sudo pod install" and run on terminal