# Xcode error on flutter project Mac mini M1 2020

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos, apple-m1

after updating Xcode to 10.0.1 my app was running properly on IOS, but after updating some packages (the trigger might have been `flutter pub outdated` it stopped running.

I'm getting this error:

```
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            7.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/cx/qvs8bp1d06bgmm3xk4m9j_nh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.QyqxdV/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirEXA35l/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Users/xaviercolomes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dejybutjhkavwlbkwxxvqlussbma/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppsFlyerFramework.build/Script-DB11BDFA881B34CD788E0AC97063A831.sh: line 2: /Users/xaviercolomes/amazingApp/amazingApp-app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppsFlyerFramework/AppsFlyerFramework-xcframeworks.sh: Permission denied
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/xaviercolomes/amazingApp/amazingApp-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'webview_flutter_wkwebview' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/xaviercolomes/amazingApp/amazingApp-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'flutter_secure_storage' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/xaviercolomes/amazingApp/amazingApp-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'Amplitude' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/xaviercolomes/amazingApp/amazingApp-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'url_launcher_ios' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/cx/qvs8bp1d06bgmm3xk4m9j_nh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.QyqxdV/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirEXA35l/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

I tried updating cocoapods but then I'm getting new errors, nothing that I did in the past seems to work now.

This is my flutter doctor:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.3, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm, locale en-ES)
    • Flutter version 3.3.3 on channel stable at /Users/xaviercolomes/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18a827f393 (7 days ago), 2022-09-28 10:03:14 -0700
    • Engine revision 5c984c26eb
    • Dart version 2.18.2
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/xaviercolomes/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Users/xaviercolomes/Library/Application
      Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14A400
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Users/xaviercolomes/Library/Application
      Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/211.7628.21.2111.8193401/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (5 available)
    • DN2103 (mobile)            • GUE6WSIJ49TGMFWW                     • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
    • iPhone 13 Pro Max (mobile) • 7D294FC3-A53B-461E-BFAF-F67FCE103F52 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-0 (simulator)
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile) • C1EE2EA1-D4AC-4AF0-A85D-142E742473C9 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 105.0.5195.125

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change **Minimum Deployments**('IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET') to 11 :

[image]

[The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, in Flutter How can I change the minimum IOS Deploying Target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973136/the-ios-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-set-to-8-0-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks Хуршид Собиров but it didn't work, it still gives the same error

Comment: Actually after doing all the steps in the link provided I get this error:

`Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update

Error running pod installp
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.`

Comment: Run the following command from the terminal:   cd ios && pod install --repo-update

Comment: I had this error 
`You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

[1]    30788 abort      pod install --repo-update`

Comment: Solved now! Omg that was tough, I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352212/you-may-have-encountered-a-bug-in-the-ruby-interpreter-or-extension-libraries and this https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652822
thanks for the help Хуршид Собиров!