# Try use brew install gmp and brew install gnupg and im getting a Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby, terminal, homebrew

I am very new to this command terminals so please if anyone can dumb it down for me what I am supposed to do. I signed up for a coding boot camp and they are requiring I install these packages I am using a 2022 MacBook Pro with a Apple M1 Pro chip

```
allen@Alls-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew install gmp
Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
brew bundle dump
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arch -arm64 brew install "package-name"
```

replace 'package-name' with the package you want to install.

Spent 15 seconds to find the answer ;/

here is link -

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963370/error-cannot-install-in-homebrew-on-arm-processor-in-intel-default-prefix-usr`